# How to convert a series of directories into Git commits?

Tags: git, version-control

I have an old legacy codebase with releases saved in directories tagged by date...

```
...
../20110819/
../20120105/
...
```

We moved to git a few months ago and I took a few commits from the old releases as starting points, and have developed on top.

I have two questions, the first of which is more important:
How do I convert this series of directories into git commits? Preferably, this would be automated in a script.

Second, how can I add the commits I've made back on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one expands on Justin's answer. The rebase procedure afterwards can be complicated, so I didn't include it. It amounts to `git rebase -i newroot master`, but there are subtleties as far as merging/adding/deleting. For example, I had to clean up files that were removed (these don't get picked up, because we are only adding files).

If you are, as I was, wanting these legacy imports to be "before" the commits in the current repo, you will want to do something like `git checkout --orphan newroot`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import datetime as dt

LEGACY_PATH = '/path/to/legacy'
REPO_PATH = '/path/to/repo'
AUTHOR_NAME = 'Your Author <your@author.com>'

def main():
    os.chdir(REPO_PATH)
    #We assume you are on the branch where you want to import
    #Otherwise the following line will do
    #os.system('git checkout --orphan newroot')
    subdirs = sorted(os.listdir(LEGACY_PATH))
    print subdirs

    for d in subdirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(LEGACY_PATH, d)
        legacy_date = dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d').isoformat()

        cmd = 'git --git-dir=%s/.git --work-tree=%s add .' \
                % (REPO_PATH, fullpath)
        print '\n', cmd
        os.system(cmd)

        os.chdir(REPO_PATH)
        cmd = 'git commit -m "Import changes from legacy version %s" \
                --date=%s \
                --author="%s"' \
                % (d, legacy_date, AUTHOR_NAME)
        print '\n', cmd
        os.system(cmd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code:

```
git init newrepo
for each directory in the proper order (looks like you can just do a numeric sort there, unless there are exceptions to the naming convention)
do
  remove everything in newrepo except for .git
  copy entire contents of tree into newrepo, without the <date>/ prefix
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "some suitable message mentioning the date/version"
done
```

You might be able to skip the copying with proper usage of `git --git-dir=... --work-tree=...` options, but I've usually just done the above for similar cases (granted, in the cases where I've done this, all the "versions" were being unpacked from a series of archives, rather than living in a series of directories, though).

Answer (score 1):

*I haven't explicitly tested this but it should work.* Make a copy of your git repo and test it against that so you don't lose anything important if something goes wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

LEGACY_PATH=/path/to/legacy/versions
REPO_PATH=/path/to/git/repo

cd ${REPO_PATH}
git checkout -b import-legacy
for V in $(ls -v ${LEGACY_PATH}/*); do
  cd ${V}
  git --git-dir=${REPO_PATH}/.git --work-tree=${REPO_PATH} add -A .
  git commit -m "Import changes from legacy version ${V}"
done
git rebase --interactive master
(reorder your changes, if needed, on top of the last legacy import)
git checkout master
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: This wasn't quite right (will edit the error), and was missing a few of the features I wanted like committing to the correct date. I'll post a Python version I cooked up.